# Earliest known usage of letter gamma "Γ" for reducible representation in group theory

Tags: mathematics, terminology, quantum-mechanics, chemistry, group-theory

Does any know the earliest known usage of the Greek letter gamma for showing a reducible representation of a group? This symbolism is commonly used in character tables in chemical applications of group theory, for example as shown here. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Yes, some authors use an index i in Γ to show that it is irreducible.

Comment: I agree. The convention at least in the chemical literature is to use capital gamma for reducible and capital gamma with i as superscript or subscript as irreducible representation.

Comment: Citation needed. This excerpt only involves $\color{red}{\textrm{ir}}$reducibles (for which $\color{blue}i$ is an enumeration $\color{blue}{\textrm{i}}$ndex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Early examples are Burnside ([1910](//zbmath.org/?q=an:41.0173.01), [pp. 324-325](//books.google.com/books?id=qAj_sgkzjvAC&pg=PA1266); [1911](//zbmath.org/?q=an:42.0151.02), [p. 271](//books.google.com/books?id=rGMGAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA271)) where $\color{red}{\textrm{ir}}$reducible representations are called $\Gamma$, $\Gamma_1$, $\Gamma_2$, etc. (Earlier in ([1901](//zbmath.org/?q=an:32.0140.01)) he had called them $G_1$, $G_2$, etc.)

Speiser ([1923](//zbmath.org/?q=an:49.0081.01), p. 104; [1927](//zbmath.org/?q=an:53.0104.12), [p. 151](//books.google.com/books?id=Ak59BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA151&dq=%22Ist%20nunmehr%20eine%20Darstellung%22)) uses the same convention, but allows $\Gamma$ to be reducible.

Note that for them a *representation* is not a homomorphism to $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ (a map) but rather its image (a group). So your question morphs into: who first wrote $\Gamma$ for a group of linear substitutions? Now *that* goes back to at least Jordan ([1870](//zbmath.org/?q=an:03.0042.02), [pp. 221 sq](//archive.org/stream/traitdessubsti00jorduoft#page/221)).

Comment: Thank you. I checked the unabridged Oxford dictionary, it also traces the earliest use of the term representation, by Burnside in 1897. "*W. Burnside Theory Groups of Finite Order ii. 22 As long as we are dealing with the properties of a group per se, and not with properties which depend on the form of representation, the group may, if convenient, be replaced by any group which is simply isomorphic with it*." Does anyone know if Frobenius papers on groups have been translated? I could not find them. Thanks.

Comment: @M.Farooq [Frobenius](//www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=235974) introduced the German word, *Darstellung*, nearly simultaneously (18 November [1897](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=njp.32101066023605&num=994)). I don’t think he’s been translated, but Curtis ([1999](//www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1715145)) has a good exposition. Anyway, right: almost as soon as someone was in a position to call a *representation* $\Gamma$, they did. But it was really a *group* — hence, probably, the letter.

Comment: @ Francois, thank you once again. I am attaching picture from a 1933 paper by Tisza (Zeitschrift fur Physik). It seems like that Γ was not that universal symbol for representation. He uses D instead of gamma for Darstellung.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLdbH.gif) is one example of using D instead of Γ in the early literature Tisza (vide supra).